# Как использовать хеш-переменную в данных для постройки модели

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, анализ-данных

Решая задачи по машинному обучению, наткнулся на данные, в которых есть обычные переменные, их значения, но еще приложено и для каждого ID - несколько хеш-переменных.
[image: Пример]

Иногда они одинаковые для разных ID, но что с такими переменными делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы не знаете, что этот за переменная, о какой модели может идти речь? И вообще, причем тут машинное обучение? А переменная хешируется именно для того, что-бы никто - и вы в том числе - не могли узнать, что именно там записывалось.